# Распаковка zip с помощью dotnetzip

Tags: c#, zip

Использую либу dotnetzip (документацию читал), и нужно извлечь все файлы из 1-й папки, делаю так

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(@"C:\1\arch.pkg"))
{
   ZipEntry[] entr =   zip.ToArray();

   foreach (ZipEntry zp in entr) {
       if(zp.FileName.IndexOf(@"docs/xml/") == -1) 
           continue;                        
       zp.Extract(@"C:\1\");
   }
}
```

нет ли более оптимального варианта а то переберать огромный массив , не очень хочется.

Comment: Во-первых, не пойму, зачем вам `.ToArray()`, с ним же гораздо медленнее. Во-вторых, а что возвращает `zip["docs/xml"]`? `null` или не `null`?

---
Попробуйте

    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(@"C:\1\arch.pkg"))
    {
        var filteredEntries = zip.Where(entry => entry.FileName.StartsWith(@"docs/xml/");
        foreach (var entry in filteredEntries)
            entry.Extract(@"C:\1\");
    }

Comment: @VladD, спасибо работает, но не совсем понимаю как, если не тяжело можете объяснить эту строку

    var filteredEntries = zip.Where(entry => entry.FileName.StartsWith(@"docs/xml/");

Comment: @cyber_ua: ну, хм. Почитайте про LINQ-to-Objects, красивая и модная техника же! Вкратце: поскольку `zip` реализует `IEnumerable<>`, к ней можно применять `Where`, которое фильтрует по предикату-аргументу "на лету", и возвращает новый `IEnumerable<>`. По этому `IEnumerable<>` можно пробежаться циклом `foreach`.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо,понял.

Answer (score 5):

Нет. По крайней мере, с dotnetzip.

> There is no support in the zipfile format for a concept of object like "folder". You cannot operate on a "folder" that is contained in a zipfile in the same way you can operate on a folder in the Windows Explorer.
>
> There is an entry type for a directory in the zip format, but the directory is not a container object. It contains no other files or sub-directories. If you want to access a directory from within a ZipFile, you should specify the name with a trailing slash. If you extract a ZipEntry that is of type directory (in other words the IsDirectory property is true), then DotNetZip will simply create the appropriate directory in your filesystem. It will not extra t any "contained" files, because as I said, there is no containing relationship in the zipfile.

([отсюда](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/12080))

Comment: а какую альтернативу посоветуете?

Comment: Хм, я бы поставил на то, что это ограничение формата ZIP.

Comment: у меня формата pkg, чем его еще можно разпаковать?

Comment: > Хм, я бы поставил на то, что это ограничение формата ZIP.

Так и есть. Видимо, ТС ищет уже готовый велосипед. Но ничего принципиально другого там быть не может.

Comment: @cyber_ua, pkg - это всего лишь расширение в имени файла. Если приведённый вами в вопросе код работает, то вы имеете дело с Zip-архивом.
Попробуйте код, предложенный в комментарии к вопросу.